# Underlayment for Enclosed porch

Tags: tile, underlayment, porcelain

I want to install porcelain tile in my glass enclosed porch. Presently there is a 6” x 5/4” pressure treated lumber for the floor. The floor is only 2 years old and in very good condition. Can I use 1/4” cement board as underlayment?

Comment: What is the span of the 6” x 5/4” pt lumber?